# Rails + Elastic Beanstalk + Passenger: change Passenger configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Rails (4.0.13 with Ruby 2.2.3) Elastic Beanstalk app with Phusion Passenger as its application web server.

I'd like to change some of the Passenger config variables. As stated here https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#location-of-passengerfile-json, I need to put a `Passengerfile.json` in the app root directory.

However, according to this post https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=181591, it makes no difference to put the config file there. That, and the fact that I cannot seem to check the passenger variables (`passenger-status` doesn't allow me and suggests `sudo`, but with `sudo` it says `sudo: passenger-status: command not found`) has prevented me from trying to put the config file there.

So, how can I check and change the Passenger configuration values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a file named Passengerfile.json you have to call it `passenger-standalone.json`, for example if you want to change `max_pool_size` you need a file with this content:

```
{
  "max_pool_size": 3
}
```

To check the status of the passenger process you can use `passenger-status` command but you have to use `sudo` with option `-i` to let root inherits your user's environment settings.

```
sudo -i passenger-status
```

Comment: Just a heads up, but `passenger-standalone.json` is now `Passengerfile.json` in version 5. See [release notes](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/04/phusion-passenger-5-0-1-released/)